# How to use scroll snap over a number of items per scroll

Tags: css, user-interface, sass, frontend

So i'm trying to do this without any javascript. I want make it so that when i scroll, it scrolls over 4 (or multiple) items in a container. is that possible?

To make it easier to understand, here's

```
.scrollers {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: calc((150px + 2rem) * 4);
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  display: flex;
  gap: 3rem;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.scrollers.multiple {
  /* Ideas ?   */
}

/* normal scroll */
.scrollers .box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

Code pen explanation: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/hajiskyy/pen/jOzVrpK)

Comment: you can put the 4 items inside a `<div>`, so the element to snap on it became the parent div, that has the 4 children... I know is not the best solution but it is the simplest also to understand (just simple html changes)

Comment: thanks @LaaouatniAnas , i considered that at first but it's within a larger scheme of things for and so it need to be this way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright so i've figured it out. The trick is to target the child elements you want the snapping to happen on and apply the snap css stylings. In my case, i needed it to be over 4 elements so i'll target `:nth-of-type(4n + 1)`. +1 is because it's zero based.

when we apply `scroll-snap-align: start;` and `scroll-snap-stop: always;` on only those elements. it forces the scroll snapping on them.

TL;DR,

```
.scrollers.multiple .box:nth-of-type(4n + 1) {
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

Note: other child elements should not have the `scroll-snap-align` set.